# What is the fastest way to convert an imageURL from Firebase into a UIImage?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, uiimage

In my iOS app I need to take an imageURL string and convert it into a UIImage.

I wrote the below function to handle this:

```
 func getImage(urlString: String) -> UIImage {
    let url = URL(string: urlString)!
    do {
        let data = try Data(contentsOf: url)
        let image = UIImage(data: data)!
        return image
    } catch {
        print(error, " This was the error in p2")
    }
    return UIImage(named: "media")!
}
```

The issue is that this takes too long. I believe it's a solid second or longer for this to complete.

I need that time to be significantly shorter.

**Question**: Is there a faster way to get the UIImage based on an imageURL from Firebase? (maybe a cocoa-pod? or better way to write the code?)

Additional questions:

- Would this be any faster if the image in Firebase were of lower quality?
- Would it be a viable solution to lower the quality of the image right before being passed into this function?

Comment: You are loading a remote image from the Internet. It takes time. It could take a minute on a slow network connection. The proper solution is to accept the fact that it takes time and implement your UI accordingly.

Comment: @rmaddy would it help if the media I upload were lower quality (it was compressed)?

Comment: Sure, the less data that needs to be downloaded, the less time it will take to download it. But that doesn't change the fact that it is a remote download and you have no control over a user's intermittent or slow network. Just assume it will be slow at times.

Comment: Don’t use Data(contentsOf: URL) for remote resources. You should download the data asynchronously using URLSession dataTask method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A lot the prominent iOS apps (and web and mobile and general) that do a lot of downloading of images take advantage of progressive jpeg. This way your user will see at least something while the image loads and over time the image will get progressively better. As a lot of commenters have mentioned, you’re not in control of Firebase like you would be if you had your own backend server delivering the pictures that you could do performance optimizations. Therefore one of the best things you can do is implement progressive jpeg in your app.

The first link is a library that will allow you to use progressive jpeg in your iOS app. The second link is a detailed approach used at FaceBook on faster loading of images.

https://www.airpair.com/ios/posts/loading-images-ios-faster-with-progressive-jpegs

https://code.fb.com/ios/faster-photos-in-facebook-for-ios/

Comment: I am unable to use the project you included getting Could not build Objective-C module 'Concorde' because concorde does not seem to support swift 4+: https://github.com/contentful-labs/Concorde/issues/20 Can you provide alternatives? Or another solution

Comment: If this were my project I’d forget about using cocoa pods, instead manually include that library by downloading it from github, and do the migration manually the the current swift version by looking at all the errors and replacing with up to date code. I imagine Xcode will provide a lot of the necessary suggestions.

Comment: If it’s objective-c then you can use and objective-c to swift bridging header. That way you can use obj-c classes in your swift code. That’ll save you time.  https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/imported_c_and_objective-c_apis/importing_objective-c_into_swift

Comment: This does not ^ seem to do the progressive download

Comment: You sure? There’s a whole section on that readme that says the you’ll be able to watch the image load (see the progressive decoding section) https://github.com/kean/Nuke/blob/master/README.md#progressive-decoding

Comment: They also have a demo for it

Comment: Could you check: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56410129/ambiguous-reference-to-member-loadimagewithprogresscompletion-when-using

Comment: Yes but I’m not at a computer right now. Later tonight I’ll check.